# wercker for sails +mongo db

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, wercker

i'm try to use [wercker](http://wercker.com/), 
but i don't know my testing can't connect into my mongodb.

i'm using sails + sails mongo, and when npm test...i'm always get error can connect into mongo db, this is my wercker.yml :

```
box: nodesource/trusty:0.12.7
services:
  - id: mongo:2.6
# Build definition
build:
  # The steps that will be executed on build
  steps:
    - script:
        name: set NODE_ENV
        code: export NODE_ENV=development
    # A step that executes `npm install` command
    - npm-install
    # A step that executes `npm test` command
    - npm-test
    # A custom script step, name value is used in the UI
    # and the code value contains the command that get executed
    - script:
        name: echo nodejs information
        code: |
          echo "node version $(node -v) running"
          echo "npm version $(npm -v) running"
```

this is my error message :

```
warn: `sails.config.express` is deprecated; use `sails.config.http` instead.
Express midleware for passport
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
  1) "before all" hook
  2) "after all" hook

  0 passing (2s)
  2 failing

  1)  "before all" hook:
     Uncaught Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?
 Error details:
{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }
      at net.js:459:14

  2)  "after all" hook:
     Uncaught Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?
 Error details:
{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }
      at net.js:459:14
```

Answer (score 1):

While out of the box, MongoDB has no authentication so you just have to provide to sails the right host and port.

1. Define a new connection in your sails app in `config/connection.js`:

```js
    mongodbTestingServer: {
        adapter: 'sails-mongo',
        host:    process.env.MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR,
        port:    process.env.MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT
    },
```

Concerning `MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR` and `MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT`, these 2 environment variable are created by Wercker when you declared a mongo service. **Like That, you will be able to connected your application to your database with the right host and port**.

2. Add a new environment in your sails sails app in `config/env/testing.js`. It will be used by Wercker :

```js
module.exports = {
    models: {
        connection: 'mongodbTestingServer'
    }
};
```

3. In your wercker file `wercker.yml`. I recommend you to use the *ewok stack* (based on Docker), you can active it in the settings of your application. Here is some useful informations concerning [migration to Ewok stack](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/faq/migration-tips-v2.html). My example use a box based on a Docker image.

```
# use the latest official stable node image hosted on DockerHub 
box: node
# use the mongo (v2.6) image hosted on DockerHub 
services:
  - id: mongo:2.6
# Build definition
build:
    steps:
    # Print node and npm version
    - script:
        name: echo nodejs information
        code: |
            echo "node version $(node -v) running"
            echo "npm version $(npm -v) running"
    - script:
        name: set NODE_ENV
        code: |
            export NODE_ENV=testing
    # install npm dependencies of your project
    - npm-install
    # run tests
    - npm-test
```

To see all environment variables in your Wercker build, add this line :

```
- script:
    name: show all environment variables
    code: |
        env
```

It should work.